# Valid JSON giving JSONDecodeError: Expecting , delimiter from variable not raw string

Tags: python, r, json, airflow

Let's imaging the response from the server

```
{
    "overriding_parameters": {
        "jar_params": [
            "{\"aggregationType\":\"Type1\",\"startDate\":\"2022-05-10\",\"endDate\":\"2022-05-10\"}"
        ]
    }
}
```

Json is valid:
[image]

In order to parse it via `json.loads()`, you need to add `r` first.

So the result should be

```
import json
dummy_response = r'{"overriding_parameters": {"jar_params": ["{\"aggregationType\":\"Type1\",\"startDate\":\"2022-05-10\",\"endDate\":\"2022-05-10\"}"]}}'
dummy_dict = json.loads(dummy_response)
```

But, this server response is coming from airflow xcom:

```py
response = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='get_run_list')
type(response) # str
metrics = json.loads(response)
```

How to correctly substitute `r` in this case? `type(response)` is str.

I tried this one

```py
json.loads(r"{}".format(response))
```

But it doesn't work.

How to handle it properly if the response is a variable, not raw str?

Comment: Could you show where you are pushing to xcom?

Answer (score 0):

considering your response is what you've provided; couldn't you use json.dumps?

```
import json

response = {
    "overriding_parameters": {
        "jar_params": [
            "{\"aggregationType\":\"Type1\",\"startDate\":\"2022-05-10\",\"endDate\":\"2022-05-10\"}"
        ]
    }
}

jsonObject = json.loads(json.dumps(response))
```

Comment: Your example is not quite valid since your response has an initial dict type, but mine - is string